# pymongo Query Existing Collection

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I have a database `SensorReadings` which has a collection `MeterReadings` this is populated using another script so the collection already exists.

I am setting up a script to query the `MeterReadings` collection. It looks like the following.

```
## Imports ##
import pymongo

## Variables ##
url = "mongodb://localhost:27017"

## getDBConnection ##
def getDBConnection():
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(url)
    db = client["SesnorReadings"]
    collection = db["MeterReadings"]
    readings = collection.find_one({})
    for res in readings:
      print(res)
```

`readings` is returning a `None` type. The exact error I get is shown below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    conn = functions.getDBConnection()
  File "functions.py", line 19, in getDBConnection
    for res in readings:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

When I add an insert statement hwoever first and then query using the `find_one` method, it will create a new database `SensorReadings` with a collection `MeterReadings` in it.

```
## Imports ##
import pymongo

## Variables ##
url = "mongodb://localhost:27017"

## getDBConnection ##
def getDBConnection():
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(url)
    db = client["SesnorReadings"]
    collection = db["MeterReadings"]
    readings = collection.find_one({})
    mydict = { "name": "John", "address": "Highway 37" }
    x = collection.insert_one(mydict)
    for res in readings:
        print(res)
```

The above code returns:

```
_id
name
address
{'_id': ObjectId('5fc679dd439f1a27d0bb0c5e'), 'name': 'John', 'address': 'Highway 37'}
```

However in the Mongo terminal there are now two `SensorReading` databases. One has the correct data and one has the data I just added using the above snippet.

```
> show dbs
SensorReadings  0.000GB
SesnorReadings  0.000GB
admin           0.000GB
config          0.000GB
local           0.000GB
```

I just want to connect to the `SesnorReadings` database that is already created and query the `MeterReadings` collection in it.

Comment: One of those is misspelled `SesnorReadings`

Comment: Thank you, it was a long day hahah

Answer (score 1):

`find_one` returns one document. Use `find` to get all documents.

And you have a typo in collection name as pointed out in the comments.